# 'RegisterAPI' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to display a register_view here and I'm getting the error. I have made some changes to the views fil,e but i am still getting the errors and i don't know how to fix it. Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializer import RegistrationSerializer


class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    user_serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user = user_serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "user": RegistrationSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
                "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
            })
        else:
            data = user_serializer.error
        return Response(data)
```

And here is what is in  my serializer.py file:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, CharField
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError as Error
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegistrationSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    password2 = CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "password",
            "password2"
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self):
        user = User(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username']
        )
        password1 = self.validated_data['password1']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password1 != password2:
            raise Error({'password': 'Passwords must match'})

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `serializer_class` attribute instead of `user_serializer_class`

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
```

to

```
class RegisterAPI(APIView):
```